# How to pull a single value from json in Azure Logic Apps:?

Tags: json, azure, parsing, kql, azure-sentinel

I have the following. I'm trying to pull a single value out but no matter how I try and pull it, I get nothing.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could get the expected results after using the below expression for my logic apps. For demonstration purposes, I have stored the value of your sentinel in compose and tried to retrieve from the same.

```
outputs('Compose')[0]['Estimated Price']
```

Below is the flow of my logic app

[image]

Results:

[image]

Note: If your query returns multiple Estimated values in a single run, you cannot initialise the value but you can use set the value using Set_Variable along with Parse_Json instead as below.

[image]